# Make ctrl-j and ctrl-k work like they do in less?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, scrolling

I would like to use ctrl-k and ctrl-j to not only move the cursor up or down (by lines), but also to scroll the portion of the document that is visible.  Effectively, leave the cursor where it is and move the document past it.

I can accomplish this for the most part using:

```
:nnoremap <c-j> j<c-e>
:nnoremap <c-k> k<c-y>
```

However, this has two issues:

1. Minor issue: when the cursor is at the bottom visible line (`L`) or the top visible line (`H`), then an extra line is shown by ctrl-j and ctrl-k respectively (undesirable behavior).
2. Major issue: this shortcut doesn't work with counts.

How can I improve on my solution to avoid these issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve the first issue using a bit of logic in the mapping so that the `j`/`k` is emitted after `<c-e>`/`<c-y>` if the current line is the bottom/top line of the window...

```
:nnoremap <expr> <c-j> winline() == winheight(0) ? "\<c-e>j" : "j\<c-e>"
:nnoremap <expr> <c-k> winline() == 1 ? "\<c-y>k" : "k\<c-y>"
```

For the count, you can create user commands that accept counts. Should be able to combine above with that. See `:h usr_40.txt` and `:h user-commands`. (I'd help but must depart for a while.)

**Update:** Actually, thanks to [@ChristianBrabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt) we have [a better, easier approach to handling counts](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15200/make-ctrl-j-and-ctrl-k-work-like-they-do-in-less/15202?noredirect=1#comment26009_15202) which is to use the read-only Vim variable `v:count1`. This contains the count given for the last Normal command and it works with mappings. (There is also a `v:count` which is almost the same thing but `v:count1` will contain default value 1 if no count was entered.) So that gives us:

```
:nnoremap <expr> <c-j> winline() == winheight(0) ? "\<c-e>".v:count1."j" : "j".v:count1."\<c-e>"
:nnoremap <expr> <c-k> winline() == 1 ? "\<c-y>".v:count1."k" : "k".v:count1."\<c-y>"
```

(We only prepend the count to the second motion as the first gets the count implicitly.)

Comment: something like this I guess: `:nnoremap <expr> <c-j> winline() == winheight(0) ? "\<c-e>".v:count1."j" : "j".v:count1."\<c-e>"` Note: this has still some problems when the cursor is on the last line of a buffer, because then the `j` will fail

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Oh, cool, no user command necessary? That variable is ringing some bells for me now that you mention it. As for problems with last line and `j` I tested it without any issues. (Or do you mean once the count is added?) Will re-check when I'm front of a computer (and try your count idea). Thanks!

Comment: The problem is, if the cursor is on the last line and that line is not the last window line. I guess the mapping should look like this:
`:nnoremap <expr> <c-j> line('.') == line('$') ? "\<c-e>" : (winline() == winheight(0) ? "\<c-e>".v:count1."j" : "j".v:count1."\<c-e>")`
I guess, it would be time to refactor this into a function to work correctly ;)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I'm not seeing any issue with last line when it's not at the bottom of the window. It doesn't appear to behave any differently than if I hit plain `j`. I'll look closer but for now I've put the base mappings in.

Comment: @B Using this mapping: `:nnoremap <expr> <c-j> winline() == winheight(0) ? "\<c-e>".v:count1."j" : "j".v:count1."\<c-e>"`, `:h usr_toc`, `:norm! Gz.` Note, you won't be able to scroll the content upwards, although using `<c-e>` it still works. This is because the `j` fails and the mapping is aborted. (And it works, if you go up one line and press <c-j>)

Comment: I think we're looking at this differently. OP wants to "leave the cursor where it is and scroll the document past it". My interpretation of that as well as what feels correct to me is that I wouldn't want it to keep scrolling text up once the cursor reaches the last line. If I did I'd just use `<c-e>` at that point. OP's call, though.

Comment: Works great!  One odd bug I noticed, that I don't quite understand (but doesn't hinder usability): if you `50<c-k>` at the top of the document, and then `<c-j>`, you get very odd results.  Likewise for moving past the bottom.

Comment: @BLayer, could you look at this again please?  Something peculiar goes on with the counts.  For instance, try (from the middle of the screen in a long document) `2<c-k>` followed by `<c-j><c-j><c-j>`.

Comment: @Wildcard Works for me. What's the problem?

Comment: Interesting, I just double-checked on an Ubuntu VM with Vim 7.4 and had no issues.  On Mac, with Vim 7.3, if a `2<c-k>` is followed by `<c-j>`, the `<c-j>` and each subsequent `<c-j>` or `<c-k>` (until another command is run or a count is given) will move the cursor one line as expected but scroll the view *two* lines.  Like the stale value of the count that was read earlier is applied to the subsequent view adjustments, but not to the cursor adjustments.  Not a major issue, just a wild bug.  Probably I should just find out how to update Vim on this Mac.  (MacVim 8.0 has no problem either.)